# Get String from Location Android

Tags: android, string, gps, location

I found a great function which gives me possibility to get Location quickly.
After that i want to display its (longitude and latitude) but it doest work still i get 0.0 / 0.0.

here's code

What should i do if i want display this latitude and longitude mostly I'm interested in function getLastKnownLocation because i want display this data without using GPS or Internet

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

{

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;
private static final float MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
public EditText lokalizacja;
public Button pobierz;
private static Context context;
LocationManager locationManager;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude ; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude



public static Context getContext()
{
    return context;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lokalizacja = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pobierz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    pobierz.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{   

    getLocation();  

}


public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude =  location.getLatitude();
                         longitude = location.getLongitude();


                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                             latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String napis = String.valueOf(latitude+ "\n" + longitude);
      lokalizacja.setText(napis);
    return location;

}
```

}

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() only returns the last fix. So if no location providers are being updated the return value of getLastKnownLocation() will not change. Its better to use onMyLocationChange() function

Comment: Ok i know it but if for example i used before maps with GSM or GPS and i get some location then i turn off gsm/gps it should works? but it doesn't

Comment: you are using network to get location right? and you are Turing off the GPS right?

Comment: In that case your condition must be if (!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled) { instead of if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) { as you never go to else part

Comment: Not really, imagine that we have 2 apps one gives you your location by GPS (getting longitude and latitude) and it is launch firstly. Then i open my app which gives me last remembered location(this which i get before). Sometimes I missclicked and i launch google maps (without gps/gsm) and it shows me this last remembered location and here's question how to get that. Main idea of this app is quicly get location and waiting for gps/gsm  takes to much time but all the time when we use internet or gps some data are send with our location i want get it

Comment: Can you get your application to somehow store the last known location, so in the event of no network provider or GPS being available, you can fall back to the saved location as a default?

Comment: @ask4solutions so tell me is there option to get last remembered location and display it ? or just get location without gps/network ?

Answer (score 0):

As flow never enter the else part due the following condition

```
 if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled 
        } else {
```

You need to have condition something like this

```
 if (!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled 
        } else {
```

or first check for GPS and then after network

Comment: How do you set values for longitude and latitude variables, if no GPS or Network is enabled?

Comment: @AndrewFielden values are set in else part

Comment: by this function GetLastKnownLocation ? but it doesn't work. I think that for example google maps all the time get some infromation about your location if your gps or netwoer are enabled, then if you turn off they still remember the same location but if you turn on gps/network again it's just update your location and that's what I'm trying to do get this remembered location

Comment: Sounds like Google Maps is somehow caching the last known location. Your app needs to do the same.

Comment: but how, i think that this function works good but i made some mess

Comment: When your app runs, what does this expression evaluate to?
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled). Is it true or false?

Comment: It depends if one of gps/network is enabled it get location from gps/network but if both are disabled we want to display last remembered location

Comment: So if both are disabled, how do you get the last remembered location? That code is not shown.

Comment: you don't see getLocation function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403819/get-string-from-location-android

Answer (score 0):

For the first time, for getting your current location, you want to enable gps or network in your device. After getting lat and lng create a preference and save these values to preference. So make some changes in your getLocation() method.

If gps and network are disable try to return the saved value from preference.

Comment: not exactly what I want to do becouse it must work and update always after i use network or gps

Comment: the saved location is only showing when the gps and network is disabled. Otherwise you must update the preference with new location. So you can get the last updated location from preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```